# Let K be event of drawing a king out of a standard 52 card deck and let D be a diamond card.

Tags: probability

Let K be event of drawing a king out of a standard 52 card deck and let D be a diamond card.
 What does P(K|D) Represent and what is it?

So, that means what is the probability of a king given that you have a diamond card.

So that's the probability of (king intersection diamond)/(probability diamond)

(1/13)/(1/4) = 30.7%

That seems very high to me, the chance of having a king given that you have a diamond card is 30.7%?

Comment: Check your probability for (king intersection diamond) again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So, that means what is the probability of a king given that you have a diamond card.

Yes.   Now there are thirteen diamonds and one of them is a king, so...

> So that's the probability of (king intersection diamond)/(probability diamond)
>   (1/13)/(1/4) = 30.7%

No.   The probability for king of diamonds is much lower than $1/13$; there are fifty-two cards and one of them is the king of diamonds, so...